# Confused about working with git branches and forks

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to collaborate on a Git repo and confused about how to go about it:

Master repo: http://myrepo/prodcode

- User1 created a fork: http://user1repo/prodcode
- Updates made to branch: third-branch

I need to make updates to the third-branch but I'm being told to make my own branch from the third-branch.  How would I do this? Also, is this the right way to collaborate on making changes to the master repo?

Answer (score 1):

Forks are – more or less – branches on a different server. If you need to base your branch off of `third-branch`, you have to clone the repository first which contains this branch:

```
git clone https://example.com/repository.git
```

Cloning fetches all branches and all commits (contained in this single repository/fork). It automatically creates a "remote" with name `origin`.

Then create a new branch starting from `third-branch`:

```
git checkout -b your-branch origin/third-branch
```

Then work on your branch and provide it to your peers or push it to your own fork. To be able to push, you either need permissions in the existing repository, or you create your own repo/fork.

To add multiple remotes to your local clone, use the `git remote` command:

```
git remote add myfork https://yourdomain.com/yourfork.git
```

Comment: OK, so once I do the checkout, I now have the third-brach and can make changes to that and push the changes to their branch or my own fork.

Comment: @Adoyt yes exactly. You can push your branch to any repository to which you have write permissions. Depending on policy or workflow the original owners of the repository might require you to push to your own fork and they then fetch your changes and integrate themselves.